# How do I have private state variables for a childview in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-view

So I am creating this app where a user chooses the multiplication table he wishes to practice on, and the number of questions on the first view, then, by pressing a button,

it goes on to the next view which passes this data, which will then create a bank of questions for him to do

There is an error saying i cannot pass a private variable, why is this so? I have attached my code for reference

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var multiplicationTable = 1
    @State private var amountQuestions = 1
  
    
    let multiplicationTables = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    
    let amountQuestionss = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                
                Picker(selection: $multiplicationTable, label: Text("multiplicationTable")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 10) {num in
                        Text("\(multiplicationTables[num])")
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .padding()
                Text("Choose number of Questions")
                Picker("Select number of questions", selection: $amountQuestions) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 10) {num in
                        Text("\(amountQuestionss[num])")
                    }
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: kek(One: multiplicationTable, Two: amountQuestions)  .navigationBarHidden(true)) {
                    Button ("GO") {
                       
                          
                        
                    }
                    .padding(50)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    
                }
                .navigationTitle("Choose Multiplication Table")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                
              
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

this is the first view, here's the second view

```
import SwiftUI

struct kek: View {
    
    let One : Int
    let Two : Int
    
    @State  var Question : String

    @State  var answer = ""
    @State  var Three = 0
    @State  var Four = 0
    
    
    func nextQuestion(){
       Three = One
        Four = Int.random(in: 0...10)
        
        Question = "\(Three) * \(Four)"
        
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text("Question: What is \(Question)?")
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Amount", text: $answer)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
          
                Button ("Next") {
                   
                      
                    
                }
                .padding(50)
                .background(Color.red)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                
            
            
            
        }
        
    }
}



struct kek_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        kek(One: 1, Two: 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no error saying you "cannot pass a private variable". There *is* an error saying that you haven't passed anything for the `Question` parameter of `kek`. By the way, it's common practice in Swift to start type names with a capital letter and variable/property names with a lowercase letter. Doing that will make it easier for others to read your code as well.

Comment: I am trying to make Question a variable local to the kek view. I do this by using

@State private var Question

But swiftui gives me the error "initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level"

I believe swiftui thinks that the Question variable is a parameter for the kek view. But I do not want it to be a parameter. I want it to be initialised locally by the kek view

What can I do

Comment: Give it an initial value inside kek — right now you have not specified an initial value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're getting the error as it is ok to pass a variable into another view. I modified your code to illustrate what I believe you're trying to achieve.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var multiplicationTable = 1
@State private var amountQuestions = 1

let multiplicationTables = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let numberOfQuestions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {

        VStack {
            Picker("Multiplication Table", selection: $multiplicationTable) {
                // There was an "off by one" issue in the kek View which I resolved by using the value of the array itself for the selection. Not the location in the array.
                ForEach(multiplicationTables, id: \.self) { num in
                    Text("\(num)")
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 20)
            /*
             Don't use
                .padding()
                .padding()
             Instead you can specify how large you'd like the padding to be around the view.
             */
            Text("Choose number of Questions")
            Picker("Select number of questions", selection: $amountQuestions) {
                ForEach(0 ..< numberOfQuestions.count) {num in
                    Text("\(numberOfQuestions[num])")
                }
            }

            NavigationLink {
                kek(one: multiplicationTable, two: amountQuestions)
            } label: {
                // A NavigationLink is clickable by default, so you don't need to place a button inside of it.
                // Here I used Text and formatted it just as you had with your Button.
                Text("Go")
                    .padding(50)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
            .navigationTitle("Choose Multiplication Table")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
struct kek: View {
    let one: Int
    let two: Int // note: It doesn't look like you're actually using this property. Consider removing it.


    @State private var answer = ""
    @State private var randomNumber = 0

    @State private var three = 0
    @State private var question = ""


    func nextQuestion(){
        three = one
        randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...10)

        question = "\(three) * \(randomNumber)"
    }


    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Text("Question: What is \(question)?")
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Amount", text: $answer)
                         .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
            }
            Button ("Next") {
                nextQuestion()
            }
            .padding(50)
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Circle())
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 

I am trying to make Question a variable local to the kek view. I do this by using

@State private var Question

But swiftui gives me the error "initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level"

I believe swiftui thinks that the Question variable is a parameter for the kek view. But I do not want it to be a parameter. I want it to be initialised locally by the kek view

What can I do

Comment: I see. If you give Question an initial value, such as an empty string, then you'll be able to use it locally in the kek view. Like so: 

@State private var Question = ""

That is still a String, it's just empty, but it's already initialized in the View. I believe that'll work for your purposes.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect these comments.